# Gmap with multiple marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

hi i have this code used for my map contact and i want to add 2 more places on it can you help 
me please:

```
/* --- Google Map --- */ 
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.5564021,5.8628159),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
  var image = "img/marker.png";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapOptions.center,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the position for your second and third markers and add them just as you added the first one

```
  var image = "img/marker.png";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapOptions.center,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

  var position2={lat:49.555,lng:5.861};
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position2,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

  var position3={lat:49.557,lng:5.863};
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position3,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
```

and of course, there's room for improvement if you add markers within a loop or declare a function to encapsule that task.

Answer (score -2):

I use this function to add additional markers to the map:
item is my custom object I want to add to the map (in this case its the details of a store).

I'm sure you can find what you need from here.

```
function _setDealer (item) {

    //the position of the marker
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
        markerOptions = {
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: myLatlng,
            //your map instance
            map: map,
            country: {
                name: (item.Country ? item.Country.Name : ''),
                code: (item.Country ? item.Country.Code : '')
            },
            geocoding: {
                coordinate: {
                    latitude: (item.Geocoding ? item.Geocoding.Coordinate.Latitude : false),
                    longitude: (item.Geocoding ? item.Geocoding.Coordinate.Longitude : false)
                },
                state: (item.Geocoding ? item.Geocoding.State : false)
            }
        },
        classification = item.Classification.toLowerCase(),
        image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            mapOptions.mapIcons[classification].normal.filename,
            new google.maps.Size(mapOptions.mapIcons[classification].normal.size[0], mapOptions.mapIcons[classification].normal.size[1]),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(mapOptions.mapIcons[classification].normal.center[0], mapOptions.mapIcons[classification].normal.center[1])
        ),
        marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

    marker.setIcon(image);

}
```

Comment: I believe this will work. However, it's a bit of an overkill to figure out what your code is doing when you only wanted to print a marker. Why don't you simplify it a bit so it may suit the general case?

Comment: Yes you are right, I just copy/pasted it from a project i did once.
The other answers(yours) are also correct.. use which you prefer. :)

Comment: You answer might still be useful to encapsulate marker adding, so you don't have to repeat yourself.